# Designing a Scalable Application

Tags: java, spring, rest, scalability, distributed

Starting a new project an e-commerce, that basically consists of two, main separated projects: a core application and a web client.

1. Core app would act as a service provider, the back-end for the web client (or other clients), exposing all its functionality in REST-ful web service/JSON.
2. Web client would act as a front-end and a service consumer for the core app.

Both project are mainly based on: Spring, Apache CXF, Maven, and either Tomcat or Jetty. 
Git as VCS. CouchDB as the DB. Also a distributed caching system like Memcached.

The principle is to design the project (both core and web) in a way to be scalable and distributable on several nodes on the internet.

Perhaps the subject is too big and complex to discuss in one topic; the idea is to put the main headlines that would assist on making the right decisions before going on with the implementation.

The questions:

1. Based on the technology stack above, what could possibly be missing or worth adding?
2. Any books, materials or case studies recommendation that touch on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you should structure your URLs and application state in such a way that they can either be generated statically and served via a web server like apache, or dynamically generated and served by the app server. Static content generation can be a pretty effective, reasonably straightforward way to improve performance. Having your API points to be implementation agnostic is generally a good practice anyways.

[High Performance Websites](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529307) has some great stuff. Also, check out [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) for HTTP caching.

Comment: I assume most of the contents has to dynamically generated, but its a good point to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CQRS](http://abdullin.com/cqrs/) principles. Even though great scalability is only side effect of applying CQRS, it ideally fits for [cloud computing](http://abdullin.com/cloud-computing/) which main goal is to provide elastic scalability. [Here is](http://cqrsinfo.com/video/) a awesome video from Greg Young's class.

PS. Despite most of materials are based on .NET stack, these principles are cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

@Ellead:Go through Tomcat clustering (session replication) :http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

Just take care of singleton objects in spring (keep in mind singleton is per JVM)

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned **performance and load testing** - you should measure performance of your application and scalability too:

- How is a single node coping wih high load ?
- What performance gainyou get by adding a single node ?

Do no expect or guess anything and start as soon as possible - that alone will save you fortune.

For REST-based solution look at Apache httpd and mod_jk for **load-balancing**.